# Area dragging not working

Tags: interface

The corners that would usually allow me to drag and create new areas from (along with joining or swapping them) isn't working. No marker shows up when I hover over the corners, and I only get the resizing options.

I checked to see if the controls/keybinds were messed up, but nope..  it's still "ActionZone Area" ..

Any fix to this?

Comment: Hello, what blender version are you using ?

Comment: i'm using version 2.83.5